# Equivalence to being a topological group

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Just some notation I am using:

A topological group $G$ is a group with a topology such that

$o : G^2 \to G : (x,y) \mapsto xy$

and

$inv : G \to G : x \mapsto x^{-1}$

are continuous in the associated topology.

---

From Munkres:

> Show that $G$ is a topological group if the map of $G \times G$ into $G$ sending $x \times y$ into $x^{-1} \cdot y$ is continuous, and conversely.

Can I be the first to say I find Munkres to be incredibly awkward in the wording of his questions?

I *think* he wants me to prove the following statement:

> $o$ and $inv$ are continuous $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\bar o : G^2 \to G : (x,y) \mapsto x^{-1}y$ is continuous.

I see the proof for the $\Longrightarrow$ direction, however I don't see how to prove the other way, which leads me to the idea that maybe I misunderstand what I need to prove.

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, he wants you to prove what you think. And yes, the phrasing is awkward. Start by showing that the continuity of $\overline{o}$ implies that of the inversion. Think of some prominent properties of the product topology for the remaining part.

Comment: Your proof of $\implies$ certainly is based on the fact that you can compose $\bar o$ from $o$ and $\operatorname{inv}$. Can you also somehow  compose $\operatorname{inv}$ and $o$ from $\bar o$?

Comment: Oh yes, thank you very much, everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**:
(1) First, show that, or note that $x\mapsto (x,e)$ is continuous.
(2) Show that $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is continuous, by showing that it is the composition of two continuous map.
(3) Show that $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ is continuous, by the same method of (2).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Consider the maps
\begin{alignat*}{2}
G&\longrightarrow G\times G&&\longrightarrow G\\
x&\longmapsto(x,1)&&\longmapsto x^{-1}\cdot 1
\end{alignat*}
then
\begin{alignat*}{2}
G\times G&\longrightarrow G\times G&&\longrightarrow G\\
(x,y)&\longmapsto(x^{-1},y)&&\longmapsto (x^{-1})^{-1}y=xy\\
\end{alignat*}

Comment: I have corrected a missing ${}^{-1}$, I hope I understood you correctly. Or maybe I should have deleted the existing one?

Comment: You didn't understand what I meant, but your correction made me realise I wasn't explicit enough, so it was helpful ;o)